# PHP XML error only when "included"

Tags: php, xml

Hi guys I may have to put together a test script to demonstrate this, but I think it should be a obvious answer.

I have a php script that generates an XML document. There are several functions in a common.inc.php.

When I include these functions via require_once the script executes fine but the browser thinks its HTML not xml which through a kink in my parser :)

When I cut and paste the same functions in the script it works like a champ.

Any ideas why? Has to be something I am missing with the functionality of require. I tried some of the ob functions no luck.

```
  header ("Content-Type:text/xml");


  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this happens if there is some sort of output before that xml line.  Are you sure your PHP open tag `<?php` is the very first thing in the file?  Be sure to take into account any includes, such as your common.inc.php.

I bet it has a blank line before the open tag, or after the close tag.  If you have a file that is entirely PHP, you can simply not close your PHP tag, leaving out `?>` altogether.  This ensures that any line breaks at the end of the file aren't sent to the browser.  You still need to be mindful of the beginning of the file though.

Comment: Im sure that is what it is. Thanks for the reply. WIll test this afternoon and post for sure.